# Async validation with useLazyQuery hook

Tags: apollo-client, react-hook-form

How to handle field level async validation in react-hook-form by using [useLazyQury](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery) hook of Apollo Client?

As far I understand the `useLazyQuery` hook is the only way to initialize a GraphQL request on some action (like `onClick`). Unfortunately for me this hook returns `void` and forces me to use `data` variable to get value. But. The react-hook-form requires to return a `true/false` value in asyncValidation. How to handle such case?

```js
const AsyncValidation = () => {
  const [nicknameUniqueness, data ] = useLazyQuery(NICKNAME_UNIQUENESS_QUERY)
   
  return (
    <input
      {...register('nickname', {
        validate: {
          asyncValidate: (value) => {
            nicknameUniqueness({ variables: { nickname: value } }) // returns void by Apollo documentation

            // How to get up-to-dated data here?

            return data?.nicknameUniqueness.isUnique
          }
        }
      })}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to use `useQuery` here instead of `useLazyQuery`. You just have to set `skip` to `true` in your `options` object and then you can use `refetch` to lazy load/validate your nickname as `refetch` will return the `ApolloQueryResult`. One important thing is to use an `async` function here for your `asyncValidate` function so that you can await the result of that query call.

```js
const AsyncValidation = () => {
  const { refetch: nicknameUniqueness } = useQuery(NICKNAME_UNIQUENESS_QUERY, {
    skip: true
  });

  return (
    <input
      {...register("nickname", {
        validate: {
          asyncValidate: async (value) => {
            const { data } = await nicknameUniqueness({
              variables: { nickname: value }
            });

            return data?.nicknameUniqueness.isUnique;
          }
        }
      })}
    />
  );
};
```

I made a small example to load data async using `useQuery`.

[image: Edit Apollo Client useLazyQuery Example (forked)]

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work for me. I will try it and give you a feedback.

Comment: I've tested your proposal and it works as expected. Thank you a lot